# NAV2009 No execute permission on 'E-Mail Dispatcher' CodeUnit ID5065

Tags: dynamics-nav

One my of users get this error when open RTC 2009.
"No execute permission on 'E-Mail Dispatcher' CodeUnit with ID 5065". 
She justed used it and I didn't modify anything.

I try everything such as 
re-compile C-5065, 
re-compile all CU,
add role SUPER to this user
and synchronize after every change but there's still error.

For more information. 
I didn't specify company name in Window Access Control and I have 2 companies in this DB. 
User cannot access the real company but can access test company ! 
This make me very confused.

Someone please help. 
Thank you.

Comment: Can you debug and see where this CU is called from? Prob you have certain setting enabled in real company (and disabled in test company) that triggers this CU.

Comment: ummm.... It's appear after choose server address and company. Where should I debug ?

Answer (score 0):

I think this is a license problem. 
Are you using a different license then your customer? You should find out what modules are not allowed in the customer license.

In the real company there probably are settings that trigger the CU 5065. 
Perhaps in the marketing setup?

Comment: Same license and using windows authentication. I tried login with this username in my notebook and error occured too. 

I also set my role same as this user but it's not happen with my windows authen.